# Updating column for associative array not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update two columns risk2 and comment2 in the review table.

The table contains

```
pid, question, risk1, comment1, risk2, comment2
```

I have successfully inserted the values in the pid, question, risk1, and in commnent1 using INSERT, however, now I am trying to UPDATE the table where I am updating the values of question, risk1, comment1, risk2 and comment2. I am getting a blank columns for all of these. This is the code I am using where I am retrieving the data from the data base and trying to update the fields.

```
<?php
$pid = isset($_GET['pid']) ? $_GET['pid'] : die('ERROR: Record ID not found.');

// include database connection

include 'config/database.php';

// read current record's data

try
    {

    // prepare select query

    $query = "SELECT * FROM review WHERE pid = '$pid'";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

    // execute our query

    $stmt->execute();
    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

    // echo $num;

    if ($num > 0)
        {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
            extract($row);
            $questionList[] = $question;
            $risk1List[] = $risk1;
            $comment1List[] = $comment1;
            $risk2List[] = $risk2;
            $comment2List[] = $comment2;
            }
        }
    }

// show error

catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
    die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }

?>

<?php

// include database connection

include 'config/database.php';

try
    {
    $questions = $_POST['questions'];
    $risk1 = $_POST['risk1'];
    $risk2 = $_POST['risk2'];
    $comment1 = $_POST['comment1'];
    $comment2 = $_POST['comment2'];
    $totalQuestion = sizeof($questions);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $totalQuestion; $i++)
        {
        $InsertQuestion = $questions[$i];
        $InsertRisk1 = $risk1[$i];
        $InsertComment1 = $comment1[$i];
        $InsertRisk2 = $risk2[$i];
        $InsertComment2 = $comment2[$i];
        $query2 = "UPDATE review SET question = '$InsertQuestion',  
                      risk1 = '$InsertRisk1', comment1 = '$InsertComment1', 
                      risk2 = '$InsertRisk2', comment2 = '$InsertComment2' 
                      WHERE pid = '$pid'";
        $stmt2 = $con->prepare($query2);
        $stmt2->execute();
        }
    }

catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
    die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }

?>



<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]. "?pid={$pid}");?>" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
  <td><strong style="font-size: 16px;"><font color="blue">Project ID</font></strong></td>
  <td><input type='hidden' name='pid'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($pid, ENT_QUOTES);  ?></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>Risk1</th>
      <th>Comment1</th>
      <th>Risk2</th>
      <th>Comment2</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><textarea style="resize:none" name='questions[]'  rows="2" class='form-control'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($questionList[0], ENT_QUOTES);  ?></textarea></td>

  <td ><input type="text" name='risk1[]' class='colors form-control' style="height:30px; width:50px;" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($risk1List[0], ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" /></td>
  <td ><textarea style="resize:none" name='comment1[]'  rows="2" class='form-control'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment1List[0], ENT_QUOTES);  ?></textarea></td>

  <td ><input type="text" name='risk2[]' class='colors form-control' style="height:30px; width:50px;" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($risk2List[0], ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" /></td>
  <td ><textarea style="resize:none" name='comment2[]'  rows="2" class='form-control'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment2List[0], ENT_QUOTES);  ?></textarea></td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td><textarea style="resize:none" name='questions[]'  rows="2" class='form-control'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($questionList[1], ENT_QUOTES);  ?></textarea></td>

  <td ><input type="text" name='risk1[]' class='colors form-control' style="height:30px; width:50px;" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($risk1List[1], ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" /></td>
  <td ><textarea style="resize:none" name='comment1[]'  rows="2" class='form-control'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment1List[1], ENT_QUOTES);  ?></textarea></td>

  <td ><input type="text" name='risk2[]' class='colors form-control' style="height:30px; width:50px;" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($risk2List[1], ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" /></td>
  <td ><textarea style="resize:none" name='comment2[]'  rows="2" class='form-control'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment2List[1], ENT_QUOTES);  ?></textarea></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<td>
<input type='submit' value='Save Data' />
</td>

</form>
```

When I echoing all the variables, they are showing the desired values.

Desired out put is to update any values in the question, risk1, comment1, risk2, and comment2 coulmn in the table.

Comment: "When I echoing all the variables, they are showing the desired values" - Really? So what is `$pid`?

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: There is no point or benefit in preparing a concatenated query

Comment: Ok, maybe you should check the code you have shown us. Is this the REAL code? As it stands this should error as you do not set `$pid` to a value anywhere in this code.

Comment: There is also no point in catching an exception just so you can echo it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your script is **wide open** to a SQL Injection attack. 
I'd personally recommend using PDO (as opposed to mysqli - it has an exception class to handle any problems that may occur) for this, but that's up to you. It still stands however, that you **need** to parameterise this properly; If someone were to pass `submittedvalue'; drop table review;--` as a POST parameter, you can probably figure out exactly what will happen.

Secondly, you're not setting the value of `$pid`, so MySQL is going to update nothing.

Here's a (slightly more secure) variant using mysql_i:

```
<?php

// include database connection

include 'config/database.php';

try {
    $questions = $_POST['questions'];
    $risk1 = $_POST['risk1'];
    $risk2 = $_POST['risk2'];
    $comment1 = $_POST['comment1'];
    $comment2 = $_POST['comment2'];
    $totalQuestion = sizeof($questions);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $totalQuestion; $i++)
    {
        $pid = ''; //TODO: Set this variable
        $InsertQuestion = $questions[$i];
        $InsertRisk1 = $risk1[$i];
        $InsertComment1 = $comment1[$i];
        $InsertRisk2 = $risk2[$i];
        $InsertComment2 = $comment2[$i];

        $query = "UPDATE review SET question = ?,  
                  risk1 = ?, comment1 = ?, 
                  risk2 = ?, comment2 = ? 
                  WHERE pid = ?";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $InsertQuestion, $InsertRisk1, $InsertComment1, $InsertRisk2, $InsertComment2, $pid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close(); //Close the statement once we're done with it
    }
}
catch(PDOException $exception)
{
    die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
}

?>
```

[This article at PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) details how to use bind_param properly, but for summary:

Replace the variables in the query with question marks

Parameter 1 passes the data types of the variables you want to embed into your query.

- i = Integer
- d = Double
- s = String
- b = Blob - will be sent in packets

Parameter 2, 3, etc is where you pass the actual variables themselves. The amount of these must match the amount of characters passed in parameter 1.

The order matters. The question mark will be substituted for the first parameter, second with the second, etc.

For some further reading, check out [This W3Schools article on connecting to MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) and [This W3Schools article on prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)